# How to change the USB keyboard layout in an OpenBSD console?

Tags: keyboard, openbsd, console, keyboard-layout

<sub>*I may be abusing the word console but I mean the mode without X i.e. pressing `^+Alt F1` and then log as other user where I want to use my chosen layout with USB keyboard.*</sub>

X works, it configures the new USB keyboard to my choice when I plug it in. But the console keyboard layout is stuck to the setting specified by the kernel. I am trying to change that:

```
# usbhidctl -f /dev/uhid0 -w keyboard.encoding=us                                       
usbhidctl: Failed to match: keyboard.encoding
```

Some info about the OpenBSD version:

```
# uname -rv
4.7 GENERIC.MP#449
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does

```
wsconsctl keyboard.encoding=us
```

work?

If yes, put that in `/etc/wsconsctl.conf` to make it persistent.

Or are you saying that that would only work for PS/2 keyboards?  Maybe enabling USB legacy keyboard mode in the BIOS would help in that case?

```
wsconscfg -k
```

may also be of use.

Perhaps you need to change the device from

```
/dev/uhid0
```

to something like

```
/dev/wskbd0
```

or

```
/dev/wskbd1
```

Comment: ...almost downvoting but wsconsctl is not for manipulating usb hid devices. It is the usbhidctl -command. Forgive me if I am wrong but it is my understandig, currently... you may be on the right track. Can you clarify the last point you added?

Comment: @hhh: Your question does not state that assumption.  Did you already try `wsconscfg -k`, `usbhidctl -f /dev/wskbd1 ...`?

Comment: `wscons` has supported USB devices [since 2001](http://openbsd.monkey.org/misc/200101/msg00653.html).  Did you even try this?

Comment: @Mikel: sorry my question may be misleading but by usb console keybord I mean that I want to get just plugged usb-keyboard working in my specified layout. I tried `"-f /dev/uhid0"` to manipulate the keyboard, not wskbd1 haven't done such redirection.

Comment: `wscons` is supposed to support USB keyboards, so I suggest finding the `/dev/wskbd<number>` that corresponds to your keyboard (or using `wsconscfg` to create such a device if it does not already exist), then try `wsconsctl` on it.

Comment: clearly I confused wsconsctl and usbhidctrl. Indeed, it automatically creates `/dev/wskbd<number>` -device so `$ wsconsctl -f /dev/wsbkbd1 keyboard.encoding=us.dvorak` works fine. Thank you.

Comment: Out of interest, if you put `keyboard.encoding=us.dvorak` in `/etc/wsconsctl.conf`, and reboot, does it affect all keyboards?  If you can't reboot now, no problem, but I would like to hear when you do.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution that works in the LiveCD environment

`wsconsctl(8)` is not included in the LiveCD environment, but `kbd(8)` is included. It is also easier to remember how to use it.

```
kbd us  # Set the keyboard layout.
kbd -l  # List possible keyboard layouts.
```

You will need to edit `/etc/wsconsctl.conf` to make the change persistent.

Source: [OpenBSD FAQ - Keyboard and Display Controls](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq7.html)